# Migrating to Angular 2.0 and BindToController

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

So, I was reading about migrating to Angular 2.0 and trying to understand better ways in which directives/components could talk to each other.

I followed some of the guidelines here which suggest to utilize namespace based inheritance for sharing information between directives.([this](http://paislee.io/migrating-to-angularjs-2-0/))

It suggests: instead of $scope.someFunction(), use $scope.container.someFunction(). Same goes for variables. 
instead of $scope.variable, use $scope.container.variable.

So, currently in my project I have few directives (more of parent-child relationship) which needs to communicate with each other.

So, I am passing in a container from parent directive to all its child directives using bindToController following **Angular 1.4**.

```
directive ('myDirective', function () {
     return {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {},
     bindToController: {
       container: '='
     },
     controllerAs: 'ctrl',
     templateUrl: 'components/my-page.html',
     controller: MyController
};
```

And passing it from parent directive like

```
 <my-directive container="container"/>
```

Since I have many variables that I need to bind, is it good to move all those variables into container and bind the entire container? something like:

```
 $scope.container = {
   variable1: ...
   variable2: ...
   function1: ...
   function2: ...
}
```

or bind them individually?

```
 bindToController: {
   variable1: '=',
   variable2: '=',
   ....
 },
```

Also, I read I could use link too as well to bind which is confusing me more. Should I be using the link as below? or bindToController as above to bind the entire container?

```
 link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, controller) {
   // access controller.container.variable1 here
 }
```

Is there a good design practice? any pros or cons and ease to migrate to Angular2.0?

I understand this is bit open ended question, but some guidance, common practice would be really helpful.

Comment: Seems similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534341/angularjs-style-guides-todd-motto-vs-john-papa-vs-minko-gechev
While not exactly on Angular 2.0, I don't see anything in your code above that is specific to Angular 2.0. The above should give you some links to some nice style guides to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following process:

- Convert Angular 1.x `$scope` dependent methods to TypeScript Angular 1.x `controllerAs` methods
- Convert TypeScript Angular 1.x directives to Angular 2.0 directives

For example:

```
class ToDoListController {
    name: string;
    listItems: any[];

    newItemName: string;

    constructor() {
        this.name = "";
        this.listItems = [];
    }

    save() {
    }

    toggle(listItem: ListItem){
    }
}
```

Which is testable without a `$scope` dependency via:

```
module TypeScriptAndAngular.Controllers.Tests {
    describe("ToDoListController Tests", () => {
        var listScopeMock: Directives.IToDoListScope;

        describe("Constructor Tests", () => {

            it("Constructor sets defaults as expected", () => {
                // Arrange
                var name = "A List Name";
                listScopeMock = {
                    name: name
                }

                // Act
                var ctrl = new Controllers.ToDoListController(listScopeMock);

                // Assert
                expect(ctrl.name).toEqual(name);
                expect(ctrl.listItems).toBeDefined();
                expect(ctrl.newItemName).toBeUndefined();
                expect(ctrl.listItems.length).toBe(0);
            });
        });

        describe("Save Tests", () => {
            it("Save does nothing if no task name has been entered", () => {
                // Arrange
                var ctrl = new Controllers.ToDoListController(listScopeMock);

                // Act
                ctrl.save();

                // Assert
                expect(ctrl.listItems.length).toBe(0);
            });

            it("Save does nothing if task name is empty string", () => {
                // Arrange
                var ctrl = new Controllers.ToDoListController(listScopeMock);
                ctrl.newItemName = "";

                // Act
                ctrl.save();

                // Assert
                expect(ctrl.listItems.length).toBe(0);
            });

            it("Save adds a new item with the specified name", () => {
                // Arrange
                var taskName = "A new task";
                var ctrl = new Controllers.ToDoListController(listScopeMock);
                ctrl.newItemName = taskName;

                // Act
                ctrl.save();

                // Assert
                expect(ctrl.listItems.length).toBe(1);
                expect(ctrl.listItems[0].name).toBe(taskName);
            });
        });

        describe("Toggle Tests", () => {
            it("Toggle sets complete to FALSE if it was originally TRUE", () => {
                // Arrange
                var item = new ListItem("A new item", true);
                var ctrl = new Controllers.ToDoListController(listScopeMock);

                // Act
                ctrl.toggle(item);

                // Assert
                expect(item.isComplete).toBe(false);
            });

            it("Toggle sets complete to TRUE if it was originally FALSE", () => {
                // Arrange
                var item = new ListItem("A new item", false);
                var ctrl = new Controllers.ToDoListController(listScopeMock);

                // Act
                ctrl.toggle(item);

                // Assert
                expect(item.isComplete).toBe(true);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**References**

- [Writing Cleaner AngularJS with TypeScript and ControllerAs](http://kwilson.me.uk/blog/writing-cleaner-angularjs-with-typescript-and-controlleras/)
- [The Many Benefits of AngularJS's controllerAs](https://colinhartwig.wordpress.com/2014/11/25/benefits-of-controller-aliasing/)
- [Kicking TypeScript's Tires](http://blogs.adobe.com/bparadie/2012/10/21/kicking-typescipts-tires/)